# I have some problem due to which my code gets executed without any errors but the console disappears as soon as it appears

Tags: c++, exit, codelite

my code:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int a{};
    std::cout<<"enter number";
    std::cin>>a;
}
```

the build log for this code:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ ConstructorsAndDestructors - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/AT/Documents/OOP_basics/Constructors&Destructors'
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/AT/Documents/OOP_basics/Constructors&Destructors/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o Debug/ConstructorsAndDestructors @"ConstructorsAndDestructors.txt" -L.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/AT/Documents/OOP_basics/Constructors&Destructors'
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Furthermore, when I build the same code on a different project, it works correctly, and the console stays till I input the number and waits for pressing any key to exit.

Following is the build log when I build the same code on a different project

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ AcessingClassMembers - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/AT/Documents/OOP_basics/AcessingClassMembers'
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/AT/Documents/OOP_basics/AcessingClassMembers/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o Debug/AcessingClassMembers @"AcessingClassMembers.txt" -L.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/AT/Documents/OOP_basics/AcessingClassMembers'
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

As there's no visible difference in the build logs, then what is causing problem.

Comment: It seems that your code is compiled and linked, but it's never executed. What does your Makefile look like?

Comment: @Bob__ I am using codelite IDE and I don't know about Makefile

Comment: The console has no reason to stay open when main has been exited. Try adding `std::cin.get();` as a second function call.

Comment: @George now, I've edited the question, but the problem still exists

Comment: As Bob points out, the first line of your build log says you are building with Makefile. That could affect the result.

Comment: @stark how do I do it differently?

Comment: *Furthermore, when I build the same code on a different project, it works correctly, and the console stays till I input the number and waits for pressing any key to exit.* How does the build log look for the other project ?

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari thanks for asking that question, I've updated the question

Comment: Make sure you are actually executing the program you just compiled. In order to do that, open a console manually, navigate to the executable, verify that it has the expected timestamp, and then execute it manually. This has the nice side effect that you see any error messages, including from Windows ("could not find dll xy" etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this documentation page https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/ProjectSettings

> ## Project Settings
>
> [...]
>   When executing your program inside CodeLite, it actually runs in a terminal. The checkbox **Pause when execution ends**, which is ticked by default, means that the terminal stays open after closing the program; so any error messages or program output remains visible. If you don't need this, you can untick the box.

So, you may need to control your settings, rather than adding a spurious `std::cin` at the end of your program.